# Best practice in handling huge overlay items on Android Maps

Tags: android, maps, android-maps

I have a situation where I need to tell users where the nearby ATMs are located. The problem is if the bank has 10000 ATMs.

When I use Maps for web programmings, I usually only load ATMs on visible area. When user do panning or zooming out, I request back-end server to provide more ATMs and redraw all overlay items. But I don't think we can use this technique on mobile device.

If I use technique from https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/hello-mapview, I get a performance hit.

What is the best way to handle this? We know that there are some concerns:

1. Loading all ATMs will eat memory a lot.
2. Loading ATMs on visible area may eat a lot of data connection as users do panning. (I don't know either how to get the visible coordinate border)

I've done some experiments. Loading 1000 overlay items (ATMs) (1000 x itemizedOverlay.addOverlayItem(anAtm);  and 1 x populate()) has consumed 5 seconds.

Is there any best practice in doing this? I really hope Google would give developers the best practice.

Thanks

Comment: you can limit the amount of ATM places sent back by the server?

Comment: Have you heard about Map Clustering ? "Search this keyword. That may be one of the alternative way"

Comment: I think, I will use boundary detection just like web-based Google Maps. Load data based on the boundary. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can filter the list of ATM sent back by the server by grouping the ones which are close into an unique point , thus achieving scale dependency for your search result display.

Answer (score 0):

You are not posting your code, so I don't know if you are following what I believe is the best approach:

1-Create the itemizedOverlay

2-Add all items (ATM's) to the itemizedOverlay

3-Call populate()

4-Only after all that, you should add the itemizedOverlay to the mapview.getoverlays()

If you have the 10000 ATM already in memory, it should be almost instantaneous to do the previous steps. What may take some time is to keep redrawing the screen when you move or zoom the map, with all this markers to display.

If you are getting the ATM's from a database, then I suggest to use AsynkTask to avoid getting a ANR message.

good luck.